# Dilate an image based on a distribution

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image that show some random filled circles (e.g. see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=random%20circle&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw_LeB-eDJAhWE6IMKHZKyBFYQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=1HEmjJi-NJNf0M%3A)). I want to change these circles to make some irregular shapes. In other words, I want to define a distribution by which I can expand the circles. Clearly, the resulted new objects will not be circles anymore, because the generated objects are expanded based on a distribution which is variable; see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=irregular%20circle&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwufqN-uDJAhXIjIMKHcexAFoQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=u990vFcwIXW4JM%3A) new deformed circle.

I was wondering if there is any method that can do this? In my first try, I tried to use image dilation in Matlab, but I have no idea on how the dilation "distribution" should be used.

```
IM2 = imdilate(IM,SE)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "distribution"? more details please...

Comment: @bla: For example, you can define the amount of dilations in different directions.

Comment: You can't use morphology for that.  Morphology assumes that the structuring element is the same when applied to all pixels in the image.  Those random shapes can't be made using a single structuring element nor on a single pass.  You'll have to operate directly on the pixel level to get those "shapes".

Comment: @rayryeng: What you mean is that I should generate them directly without any morphing? Then, the question will be that how can I randomly generate such irregular shapes?

Comment: An idea I have is to perhaps generate a bunch of points hovering around a known center with a random distribution, find their convex hull, extract a mask defined by the convex hull and smooth the boundaries. You'd repeat this for different centres. If this is something that you're open to I can write an answer.

Comment: So, how do you control the convex hall size? I mean, for example, the maximum circle that can be fitted to this hall.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using dilation, a solution could be:

1. Let say Im is your original image
2. ImResult = Same(Im)
3. ImClone = Clone(Im)
4. Randomly delete pixels in ImClone. The number of pixels to delete may be a percentage, or whatever you prefer
5. ImDilate = Dilate(ImClone), with the structuring element of size N
6. Result = Maximum(Result, ImDilate)
7. If you want different size of deformations, then you iterate from step 3 to 6, with different structuring element sizes.

But what you want is more an elastic deformation. You should take a look to the free form deformation (FFD).